# Username search in file python

Tags: python

I am trying to find a username from a txt file. (I know it is not security wise, but it is for testing purposes) Below is my code I am using and where I find the username from any line in file, save it to a list and then verify the password from that list. But it only finds the first line in file. All the other usernames after line 1 gets "Username not found"

```
with open("user.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines(): 
            login_info = line.rstrip("\n").split(", ")
            while True:
                username = input("Please enter your username: ")
                if username == login_info[0]:
                    print("Username found!\n")
                    while True:
                        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
                        if password == login_info[1]:
                            print("Password correct!\n")
                            print(f"Welcome {username}!\n")
                            return options()
                        else:
                            print("Password incorrect.")
                else:
                    print("Username not found.")
```

The txt file looks like this:

admin, adm1n
pete, p3t3
mark, m@rk

Where each line has the username as first string followed by comma and then the password.

If anyone could help me or point me in the right direction for answers.

Comment: You want to know if the user provided ```username``` exists in your text file and if it exists check if password is also correct . Is it ?

Comment: Yes... that is it. But also to let user know if username does not exist and password does not exist.

Comment: What I would suggest is read the data from file and store it in dictionary and do your checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code like you are opening the file 2 times, which is unneccessary, secondly you need to check the user provided username against all the username not only `login_info[0]`

You can try something like

```py
username_password_map = {}

with open('user.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        username, password = line.rstrip('\n').split(', ')
        username_password_map[username] = password


username = input("Please enter your username: ")
if username in username_password_map:
    while True:
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if password == username_password_map[username]:
            print("Password correct!\n")
            print(f"Welcome {username}!\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Password incorrect.")
else:
    print("Username not found.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just added a while loop above the username input for it to continue asking for correct username and not just stop. But this is what I needed.